# Part of this page are not secure, firefox, wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https, cloudflare, wordpress-theme-astra

- Theme: Astra
- Template: brandstore

Have enabled in cloudflare:

- SSL/TLS> Always Use HTTPS
- SSL/TLS> Automatic HTTPS Rewrites
- Speed>Auto Minify
- Speed>Brotli

I want to remove this problem in my site

[image]

I have deleted the images that think was raising the warning, but it continue showing a warning in console tab of developer tool of the firefox browser.

Use in firefox f12 to open the developer tool, then go to the console tab and check this warning

```
Loading mixed (insecure) display content “http://kauchoplus.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/banner-03.jpg” on a secure page
```

and all in the images bellow.

[image]

If we click in the url image `https://kauchoplus.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/banner-03.jpg` the message is this.

[image]

I am using cloudflare and have self-signed SSL certificate signed in the server.

Please help me to know who is requesting that image and remove the conection no secure problem.

Comment: You are getting a 404 error on that image. it is being called from a css file from your block editor [here](https://kauchoplus.com/wp-content/uploads/uag-plugin/assets/0/uag-css-61-1673396917.css?ver=2.2.0)

Comment: Doesn't the console also say what line in your source file is generating that? It might be on the far right side of the window. When I go to the page it seems to be using a legitimate certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem, deleting a empty container spectra-block.

[image]

The spectra blocks is installed along with the brandstorm template of the Astra theme.